# More text options in titlepage

Tags: formatting, titles

Hi how can I add more text options to a title page for example matriculation number and the institute? Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}
%\titlehead{\centering\includegraphics[width=10cm]{3_Abbildungen/Deckblatt/logohs}}

\begin{center}
    Institut für Duale Studiengänge
\end{center}

\subject{Bachelorarbeit}
\title{Title}
\author{Me}
\date{6. April bis 1. Juni 2021}
\publishers{Erstprüfer: xxx\\Zweitprüfer: yyy}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Thank you all.

Comment: I would probably drop maketitle and format it all by hand much more flexible.

Comment: @daleif can you give me a simple example?

Comment: No, sorry, not at pc at the moment. You can just use the center env, and the typeset the various parts there, leave a blank line between each part

Comment: When i add some text in center env (look at edit in my question), it will set the text on another site...

Comment: Please see my added answer ...

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx} % <===============================================


\begin{document}

\titlehead{% <==========================================================
  {\Large Institut für Duale Studiengänge}\hfill%
  \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}}

\subject{Bachelorarbeit}
\title{Title}
\author{Me}
\date{6. April bis 1. Juni 2021}
\publishers{Erstprüfer: xxx\\Zweitprüfer: yyy}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

with the result:

[image: resulting pdf]

To get the matriculation number into the header change command `\titlehead` to

```
\titlehead{% <==========================================================
  {\Large Institut für Duale Studiengänge}\hfill%
  \Large 123456789}
```